# Postman Monitor / error : getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: postman

I'm configuring Postman Monitor to schedule night executions.

However I'm facing the following error in the monitor console log:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ...

Note that I'm working on the private network of my company.

When I send the request manually without the monitor it is working fine.

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: For Monitoring, the IP needs to be publicly available.

Comment: Oh ok ... And there is no way to do the same thing with private IP? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that in the header the server responds with a different name than the one you put in the URL. The name must also be resolvable by DNS or hosts file